# Regex extracking information

Tags: regex

Hope you are fine. I was trying to build a regex for extracting some strings in some documents. This is a sample of the strings I have to extract:

1. `5003t00001fJK8EAAWFri Jan 27 2023 11:37:45 GMT-0600`
2. `0033t00004A596CAARFri Jan 27 2023 11:44:04 GMT-0600`

The regex I wrote so far I have:

a) `500[\w._%+ :-]+(GMT)`

b) `(00).[0-9][\w._%+ :-]+(GMT)`

However I am getting some observations with from 1) using the b) Regex that I build.

Any suggestion?

Comment: FYI `_` is included in `\w` so you don't have to list it in your `[]`.

Comment: Maybe you need to anchor the regexp with `^` at the beginning? Otherwise `(00).[0-9]` will match `0000` after the first `t`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks I wast aware _ was included. I gave it a shot with the with ^; however, i need the 500... since it is an identifier.

Comment: Regexp (a) should match string (1), regexp (b) should match string (2) if you put `^` at the beginning.

Comment: Yeap you are right! its a match